# Updating table 2 when inserting on table 1

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have this code where I need to subtract and add the values that was inserted in table 1 to table 2. I am new in coding and currently rushing our system since we consumed many time just on one module of the system. This is the code for insert and my attempt on updating the table 2.

```
<?php 
include("../connection.php");
// ADD INVENTORY

if(isset($_REQUEST['add'])){
    // ASSIGNING VARIABLES

    $customer = mysqli_real_escape_string($connections, $_POST['customer']);
    $transaction = mysqli_real_escape_string($connections, $_POST['transaction']);
    $time = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $item = mysqli_real_escape_string($connections, $_POST['item']);
    $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($connections, $_POST['quantity']);
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connections, $_POST['price']);
    $returns = mysqli_real_escape_string($connections, $_POST['returns']);
    $damaged = mysqli_real_escape_string($connections, $_POST['damaged']);
    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($connections, $_POST['status']);

    $price1 = $price;
    $quantity1=$quantity;
    $totalprice = $price1 * $quantity1;
    $status = 0;

    $query = "INSERT INTO transac_tbl VALUES ('', '$customer', '$transaction', '$time', '$item', '$quantity', '$price', '$totalprice', '$returns', '$damaged', '$status')";

    
    addLog($connections,"Added a transaction");

    

    $execute = mysqli_query($connections, $query);

    if ($execute){

        if ($quantity > 0){
            updateIn = $inhouse - $quantity + $returns

        }
        if ($returns > 0){
            updateOut = $inhouse - $returns + $quantity

        }

        if ($damaged > 0){
            updateDmg = $dmg + $damaged

        }


    $sql = "UPDATE inv_tbl SET inhouse = updateIn WHERE id=1";

    }

    
}
header('location: index.php');
// ADD INVENTORY END
?>
```

This is the table 1 where the quantity, returned, and damaged will be added and subtracted to the other table
[image: transac_tbl]

This is the table 2 [image: inv_tbl]

Comment: And what's your question about this? Anything not working? Also, be warned that your `INSERT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: You need to inject the PHP variable `updateIn` into the SQL properly, either through concatenation, [string interpolation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), or, as noted, prepared statements. Additionally, that statement appears to only account for one of the `if` statements prior, there's two others. And further, those variables are missing their `$`.

Comment: Also, it is a good practice to use transactions (eg. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php) when running DB actions.

Comment: @NicoHaase. It does not work, the inv_tbl is not updating, I already fixed the code where I forgot to add the $ for variables

Comment: " the inv_tbl is not updating," - where's the code that updates that table? As far as I see, you only define a string that contains an `UPDATE` query, but you do not execute that anywhere

Comment: @NicoHaase It was along with the INSERT query above. once I submit this form for the INSERT what I want to happen was to also execute the UPDATE along with it<form method="POST" action="inv-add.php" id="form1" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share the code that executes the `UPDATE` query